# How to format a volume w/o a letter being assigned (IVdsAdvancedDisk::FormatPartition)

Tags: windows, winapi, ntfs, vds

I'm hoping to format a volume without a drive letter being assigned

when I call IVdsAdvancedDisk::FormatPartition() the volume is formatted

however a drive letter is assigned (and Explorer then opens the folder)

Comment: [`IVdsAdvancedDisk`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381669.aspx) does not have a `FormatDisk()` method. It has separate `FormatPartition()` and `AssignDriveLetter()` methods.

Comment: [`IVdsAdvancedDisk::CreatePartition()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381677.aspx) has a `CREATE_PARTITION_PARAMETERS` parameter that has a `GPT_BASIC_DATA_ATTRIBUTE_NO_DRIVE_LETTER` flag if you create a GPT-style partition.